# измерение RSSI в среде python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi, поиск-библиотек

возникла потребность мерить RSSI сигнал доступных точек WiFi python 3.* операционная система Ubuntu какую библиотеку можете посоветовать? в библиотеке WiFi не нашёл метода для отображения сигнала, а  в библиотеке RSSI при вызове метода. getAPinfo() возникает проблема не совпадения типов

вот такую выдаёт ошибку

```
import rssi
interface='wlx50465daf79c1'
rssi_scanner = rssi.RSSI_Scan(interface)
rssi_scanner.getAPinfo(sudo=True)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/home/sampo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rssi/__init__.py", line 305, in getAPinfo
>     all_access_points = self.formatCells(raw_scan_output)
>   File "/home/sampo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rssi/__init__.py", line 203, in formatCells
>     raw_cells = raw_cell_string.split('Cell') # Divide raw string into raw cells
> <rssi.RSSI_Scan object at 0x7f965a721710>
> ```

Comment: Да, загадочно. В Google Colab тоже в итоге выдаёт ошибку `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`, хотя всё по их таториалу делается.

Answer (score 1):

[NetworkManager.py](https://gist.github.com/alex-eri/f1302ebad4d7a936faedfffee4a475a4) - немного исправленная под новый NM версия библиотеки NetworkManager с чьего-то гитхаба. Сохрани этот файл - положи в проект.

```
import NetworkManager
import dbus.exceptions
import dbus

def scan():
    list = []
    for dev in filter(
                lambda w: w.DeviceType == NetworkManager.NM_DEVICE_TYPE_WIFI,
                NetworkManager.Device.all()
            ):
        dev.RequestScan({})
    for dev in filter(
                lambda w: w.DeviceType == NetworkManager.NM_DEVICE_TYPE_WIFI,
                NetworkManager.Device.all()
            ):
        for ap in filter(
                    lambda a: a.RsnFlags & NetworkManager.NM_802_11_AP_SEC_KEY_MGMT_PSK,
                    dev.AccessPoints
                ):
            list.append({
                'ssid':ap.Ssid,
                'strength':ap.Strength,
                'device': str(dev.object_path),
                'ap': str(ap.object_path)
                })
    return list
```

Вот эта функция вернет список сетей с уровнем сигнала strength в процентах.

Но если хочется в dB то самый простой способ разобрать вывод `iwlist scan | grep -e Quality= -e ESSID`

Библиотека rssi это и делает. В новой версии этой библиотеки [эта ошибка исправленна](https://github.com/jvillagomez/rssi_module/blob/e88922997b6c43dd0dbc26d222f21a6443dff875/rssi/__init__.py#L329). Обновите из гита

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/jvillagomez/rssi_module.git
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. есть ли возможность отслеживать mac адрес с помощь этой библиотеки?

Comment: нет ;) но могу помочь с трекингом маков на коммерческой основе